# Show that a distribution function is dominated

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Is the probability model given by the following distribution function

$F_{p}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} p(1-p)^{k-1} & \text { if } x \geq 1 \\ 0 & \text { else }\end{array}\right.$

dominated? (in which case exhibit a dominant measure and give the Radon-Nikodym derivative).

I know the definition of a dominated model:

> A model $(P_{\theta})_{\theta}$ is dominated if there exists a measure $\mu > 0$ and $\sigma-$finite such that $P_{\theta}$ is dominated by $\mu$ and $P_{\theta}$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$

But I don't know how to show that the model given by this distribution function is dominated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure you are looking for is the counting measure on the integers (or on the support of the measure associated to $F$). Notice that since $F_p$ takes all its mass on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, if the counting measure of a set is zero, then so is its probability under the measure associated to $F_p$.

Comment: thank you! i'm still a little unsure how to come up with this. What is your approach to solving this?

Comment: @vitalmath It's a good idea to note this CDF corresponds to a geometric distribution and write the associated measure as a convex combination of Dirac masses.

Comment: You mean $F_{p}(x) =\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} p^k (1-p)^{1-k} \right)\delta_{[1,+\infty[}(x)$  ?

Comment: @vitalmath No. $\mu (A) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k (1-p)^{1-k} \delta_{k}(A)$.

Comment: Ok! so if $\mu(A) = 0$ then $k \notin A$, then why $P_p(A) = 0$?

Comment: If the counting measure on the positive integers of a set is zero, the set contains no positive integers. This none of the Diracs in $\mu$ is "activated" so that it has $\mu$-measure zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132877/discussion-between-vitalmath-and-jose-avilez).